# A white line is appearing on bottom edge of the image on hover

Tags: html, css, hover, css-transitions, transform

I am having trouble with a white pixel line that appears at the bottom of every image inside  "div class gallary". The white line appears when the mouse hovers on it [I have included transform element on hover]

Also, these images are included in only "gallary" and "photo" classes and not in any other class.

The code is as follows:

```css
div.photo {
  height: 2rem;
  transition: transform .2s;
}

.photo:hover {
  transform: scale(0.9);
  cursor: pointer;
  box-shadow: 15px 15px 15px;
}

.gallary {
  max-width: 1200px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  display: grid;
  grid-gap: 2em;
}
```

```html
<div class="gallary">
  <div class="photo"><img src="https://source.unsplash.com/300x200?v=1"></div>
  <div class="photo"><img src="https://source.unsplash.com/300x200?v=2"></div>
  <div class="photo"><img src="https://source.unsplash.com/300x200?v=3"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove box-shadow from .photo and add in to the image:

```css
 div.photo {
height: 2rem;
transition: transform .2s;
}
.photo:hover {
transform: scale(0.9);
cursor: pointer;
}
.photo:hover img{
  box-shadow:  15px 15px 15px;
}
.gallary {
max-width: 1200px;
margin: 0 auto;
display: grid;
grid-gap: 2em;
}
```

```html
    <div class="gallary"> 
      <div class="photo"><img src="https://e0.365dm.com/20/12/768x432/skysports-messi-barcelona-la-liga_5220695.jpg?20201228082630"></div>
      <div class="photo"><img src="https://e0.365dm.com/20/12/768x432/skysports-messi-barcelona-la-liga_5220695.jpg?20201228082630"></div>
      <div class="photo"><img src="https://e0.365dm.com/20/12/768x432/skysports-messi-barcelona-la-liga_5220695.jpg?20201228082630"></div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try to put an image inside a `<div>` element that has borders, you will see an extra white space (around 3px) at the bottom of the image. This happens because the image is an inline-level element so the browser adds some whitespace under the baseline to adjust other inline elements. The easiest way to get rid of this is to change the default display value of the image from inline to block, i.e. apply the style `display: block;` to the images.